# Unable to run Tango C examples on Asus phone

Tags: google-project-tango

I am trying to build and run Tango C examples on the Asus ZenFone AR and they are not running.  The example code is from the Dec 15, 2017 release.  I am using Android Studio 3.0.1 and building for Android 24.  Logcat shows

```
01-28 15:54:52.037 23672-23672/? E/TangoJNINative: ERROR! Unable to load libtango_client_api.so!
01-28 15:54:52.038 23672-23672/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.projecttango.examples.cpp.pointtopoint, PID: 23672
                                                   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/libtango_device2.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.projecttango.examples.cpp.pointtopoint-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.projecttango.examples.cpp.pointtopoint-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libcpp_point_to_point_example.so"
```

Is this caused by the Android 7.0 issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46097054/google-project-tango-ndk-undefined-reference-on-functions) ?  If so, will there be working Android 7 examples released at some point?  There are other Tango apps from the Play Store on the phone which work.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your target version to 23 in the app gradle.  a warning will appear in the debug version which you'll have to ok each run, but this does not appear in the release version.

Google are discontinuing the Tango systems, so if you want to make an AR app I would suggest looking at AR Core instead, this is how google are moving forward.

Comment: I tried this, but I still get a popup error on screen with the following:    Detected problems with app native libraries (please consult log for details): libtango_client_api.so: unauthorized access to "libbinder.so"...and similar for libcutils.so, libutils.so, libgui.so...